# R - dbWriteTable Append not all data

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I'm using RmySQL to create and load data into tables on my local machine...

first of all, after db connection, I create my table like that:

```
a<-dbSendQuery(new.db, 'CREATE TABLE ALL_PLATFORMS_INFO(
                                    PLATFORM VARCHAR(15), 
                                    ID SMALLINT(5),
                                    PROBESET_ID VARCHAR(30),
                                    GENE_SYMBOL VARCHAR(20), 
                                    ENTREZ VARCHAR(15), 
                                    UNIGENE_ID VARCHAR(20), 
                                    GENE_TITLE VARCHAR(100), 
                                    DEPRECATED BOOLEAN,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (ID,PLATFORM)) 
                                    ENGINE=InnoDB;');
```

then I load a data frame with the same columns of database like that:

```
dbWriteTable(new.db, name='ALL_PLATFORMS_INFO', value=all.platforms.info.tab, row.names=F, append=T);
```

my structure all.platforms.info.tab has 67384 rows and 8 columns, but when I query my table on the database i obtain: 55050 rows...

To avoid this I used the overvrite=T flag, but in this way I cannot declare primary keys...

Why dbWriteTable behaves in this way?
How can I declare primary keys using dbWriteTable?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check in R, before inserting, if your (ID,PLATFORM) columns are truly unique?

Comment: Did you encounter any issues? Try executing `dbGetQuery(new.db, "SHOW WARNINGS")` to see whether there were any issues. And you might try running `safe.write` directly, just like `mysqlWriteTable` does, to see whether that writes all the lines to file or omits some.